# How to find initial number of bugs/vulnerabilities in sonarqube

Tags: debugging, sonarqube, defects

Is there any UI links for finding original number of bugs after fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on your project, then hover over Bugs/Vulnerabilities section. Small icon with arrow will appear:

[image: SonarQube bugs metrics]

Click it. There, you will find your project history with all metrics. You can check original bugs count there.

Comment: Is there any way to see count of critical error, blocker ,minor and major severity ??

Comment: There is Add Metrics button on that page - you can add whatever is presented on that list - included blockers, major and minor defects and so on.